# Why does Django 3.0.6 generate the urlpatterns variable using the url() function instead of the path() function

Tags: django, django-urls, django-3.0

After creating and checking I am running a Python 3.6.1 virtual environment and have Django 3.0.6 installed, I created a project. Within this project the `urls.py` file is as shown:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

However, the Django 3 documentation says the following:
"`urlpatterns` should be a sequence of `path()` and/or `re_path()` instances."(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#syntax-of-the-urlpatterns-variable)

If this is the case why does it not generate as   `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`?

Can anyone explain this? From my understanding the `url()` function is outdated/will be depreciated, but it seems Django is baking it into the project. I believe I am supposed to be using `path()` but I am not sure.

Comment: That is really odd. Are you sure you're in the right `venv` and it is activate? What does `pip freeze` and `pip --version` output?

Comment: @FlipperPA `Django==3.0.6` and `Users/justin/Desktop/website
/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)` respectively

Comment: If you do an `ls -l Users/justin/Desktop/website/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`, is there are older version of Django in there? Maybe try creating a fresh `venv`: `python3.6 -m venv my_new_venv && source my_new_venv/bin/activate && pip --version`. After verifying that that all looks correct, install Django fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path()` is a new way of generating paths that does not involve regex and it is a bit more readable

```
path('blog/page<int:num>/', views.page),
```

`re_path()` is an old regex style ( prior to django 2.0 only way to define urlconf entries it has also alias `url()`)

```
re_path(r'^blog/(?P<page>[0-9]*)/$', views.page)
```

Comment: Should I change the it to  `path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` or just use `path()` for every custom url after that?

Comment: Why do you have start of  regex char ^   in path() that makes no sense

Comment: you can mix and match whatever you like, it is personal opinion i would do all of them same way so in this case path('admin/', admin.site.urls)